# "Delete Where" cascade delete in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-key-relationship, cascade, cascading-deletes

I am trying to cascade delete rows in a join table via one of its foreign keys and it has another table related to it that I would like to remove all rows associated with this ID as well.  So it looks like the diagram below.  When I use Session.delete(reqCandObject) with hibernate it works fine and cascades through deleting the One entry from the candidate_jobReq table as well as the associated comments.  However, I want to delete *all* of the candidate_jobReq entries that have a certain candidate ID (and also delete the comments)  I tried the function below but unlike the nice hibernate.delete(object) function, this one runs into a foreign key constraint error.  How can I delete these rows while having hibernate cascade the delete for me?

[image]

```
public void deleteWhere(String selectionCase){
    Session hibernateSession = this.getSession();
    try {
        hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
        Query q = hibernateSession.createQuery("delete "+ type.getSimpleName() +" where " + selectionCase);
        q.executeUpdate();
        hibernateSession.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        hibernateSession.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate handles cascades internally. Executing a `delete` query won't trigger the internal cascades, which will result in inconsistencies / orphans. This you might have tried and faced foreign key constraint error.

There are two ways to delete a list of entities along with their child entities:

1. Select the list of entities using `selectionCase`. Iterate through the list and delete each one individually using `session.delete`.
2. Delete the records manually. Write separate `delete` statements. To avoid the violation of foreign key constraints, you need to delete child records before deleting the parents. This will perform better than the first option.

Comment: I was hoping there was a nice, built in way to quickly handle this case, I guess not :-/ oh well.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: they really should improve this behaviour!